# How can I create an artificial Android Context in a Java web app?

Tags: java, android

I have an Android JAR file. In short, this file handles some logic that I need. However, my use-case is not an Android app. I am building a web API that requires functionality provided by this Android JAR. The functionality specifically involves a **fingerprinting** method.

I am currently building the API in Java so that I can use the JAR functionality directly. However, the biggest issue I am stumbling on is when this JAR file uses built in Android calls. In this case: `android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()`.

Although I am not an Android expert, it is my understanding that this method returns a lot of information surrounding the global android environment.

Since I am not executing my API on an Android, rather web, I am looking into how I could potentially fake this so that my API still works. Is it possible to generate a fake application context so that I can generate fingerprints on my API?

Comment: It depends on what the context is being used for, but you could just edit the source code